# Android: dynamically choosing a launch activity doesn't always work

Tags: android, dynamic, android-activity, launcher

I've read a few articles here (and other places) that describe how to dynamically choose which activity to show when launching an app. Below is my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity android:name=".StartupActivity"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

StartupActivity.java

```
public class StartupActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent;
        if (RandomClass.getSomeStaticBoolean())
        {
           intent = new Intent(this, ActivityOften.class);
        }
        else
        {
           intent = new Intent(this, ActivityRare.class);
        }
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Both ActivityOften and ActivityRare are declared in the manifest (without the launcher category of course) and extend ListActivity and Activity respectively. 99% of the time the 1st activity to get shown is ActivityOften based on RandomClass.getSomeStaticBoolean().

So launching my app from the icon for the 1st time I break inside the StartupActivity.onCreate. The choice is properly made. But then any subsequent attempts to launch the app (from a shortcut or the apps menu) show the ActivityOften again. No further breaks occur inside the StartupActivity class. Despite the fact that I know that RandomClass.getSomeStaticBoolean() has changed value and that ActivityRare should appear, the 1st activity keeps popping up.

Any ideas?

Thanks, Merci, Gracias, Danke, Grazie!
Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a suggestion, you could just have one activity instead of three by choosing the content View dynamically. i.e.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (RandomClass.getSomeStaticBoolean())
    {
       setContentView(R.layout.Often);

       // Set up often ....
    }
    else
    {
       setContentView(R.layout.Rare);

       // Set up rare ....
    }
}
```

This would mean that you would have to write setup code both views in on activity, which can get a bit messy.

Comment: That would be possible but each activity class has a lot of code. I'll try this approach but would prefer if possible not to mix all the code together into 1 file. Thanks for the input! Will keep you posted on the success of it...

Comment: In the end I decided to go with the ViewFlipper. 

Example found at http://www.androidpeople.com/android-viewflipper-example

I tried the idea mentioned above but upon switching views, Android threw an exception. There is a way to remove a view before inflating and setting another one. Ultimately I went with the ViewFlipper. Also, I made my Activity a single instance activity (this avoided other exceptions when opening one on top of another and closing the top one to then use controls on the next control on the stack).

Answer (score 3):

It is happening because your application activity is loaded from the history stack.
Set `android:noHistory=true` in the manifest for both `ActivityOften` and `ActivityRare`. That should solve your problem.

Comment: true. after using this, it was recreated properly each time. but now it is no longer on the activity stack, which doesn't help my situation so much. thanks for the help!!